# Using JPA/Hibernate, how do I map a Java enum to a column in my MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, enums, jpa-2.0

I’m using Hibernate 4.3.0.Final (JPA 2.1) and MySQL 5.5.  I want to map my Java enum to a MySQL table that has corresponding values.  So my enum is

```
public enum Roles
{
    STUDENT("Student"),
    TEACHER("Teacher"),
    …

    Roles(final String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private final String name;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return getName();
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

and my table contains values like

```
+------------------------+------------------------+-------------+
| ID                     | NAME                   | ADMIN_LEVEL |
+------------------------+------------------------+-------------+
| Student                | Student                |           1 |
| Teacher                | Teacher                |          10 |
```

Then, in an entity class that represents the above table, I have

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid-strategy", strategy = "org.mainco.subco.core.util.subcoUUIDGenerator")
@Entity(name = "sb_role")
public class Role implements Serializable, Comparable<Role>
{

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-strategy")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    /* the database id of the role */
    private String id;

    @Enumerated(value=EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    /* the String name of the role */
    private Roles name;
```

However, when I run my application, I got errors like the below.  How do I enforce integrity between the enum value and the column in the database?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Student] did not match expected type [org.mainco.subco.user.domain.Roles (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:885)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.access$000(QueryImpl.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl$ParameterRegistrationImpl.bindValue(QueryImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:631)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaCompiler$1$1.bind(CriteriaCompiler.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:736)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.mainco.subco.core.repo.AbstractHibernateDAO.findByUniqueConstraint(AbstractHibernateDAO.java:104)
    at org.mainco.subco.user.repo.RoleDaoImpl.findRoleByName(RoleDaoImpl.java:26)
    at org.mainco.subco.user.service.RoleServiceImpl.findByName(RoleServiceImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.findByName(Unknown Source)
    at org.mainco.subco.resource.service.ResourceServiceIT.testFindById(ResourceServiceIT.java:95)
```

I’m not interested in writing a @Converter (there are so many values to account for), unless that’s the absolute simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Enumerated(value=EnumType.STRING)

Use the value of the ENUM 
    STUDENT
    TEACHER

Not the one you have within the parenthesis, in your database you have values starting with lowercase
Make an update in the database to make it uppercase all the values in that column, this is the easiest solution and it should work, and doesn't affect data integrity. XD.